# 2 Outer Apply's when used together produce same result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of transactions where i would like to get associated transactions from the same table. My main query will bring back any transactions after a certain date for my main transaction code 1234.

The 2 Outer Apply's i have i would like to get back the 111 and 222 transactions that have occured withing 10 days of any 1234 transactions from the main query.

```
SELECT 
        f.dID,
        f.edID,
        f.tTypeID,
        f.Amount,
        f.MKey,
        count(e.MKey) [111 Trans],
        sum(e.amount)[111 Amount],
        count(d.Key)[222 trans],
        sum(d.Amount) [222 Amount]


FROM wh.fct.Account f 

    JOIN wh.fct.ttype tt 
        ON tt.tTypeID = f.tTypeID
           AND tt.bID = 3
           AND f.dID >= 20221101
           AND tt.TrnCode = 1234
           AND f.MKey = 1234
          

    Outer APPLY(
            select f1.InstId,f1.MKey,f1.Amount from wh.fct.Account f1 
        where f1.MKey = 1234567
           AND f1.tTypeID = 1111
           AND f1.bID = 3
        and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f1.edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
              group by f1.InstId,
                  f1.MKey,
                  f1.Amount
    ) D

        Outer APPLY(
        Select InstId, MKey, f2.amount from wh.fct.Account f2
        where f2.MKey = 1234567
           AND f2.tTypeID = 1111
           AND f2.bID = 3
            and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f2.edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
         group by 
                f2.InstId,
               f2.MKey,
               f2.amount
                    ) E

 group by

        f.MKey,
        f.dID,
        f.edID,
        f.tTypeID,
        f.Amount
```

Above is what i have tried to achive this, InstId is the unique instance that i am trying to group on.
For my 111 transactions i would expect to see 1 and for 222 transaction i would expect to see 5 but the but for the outcome i would see 5 for both.

When running each outer Apply in isolation the above is what i get but together they return the same result.

Comment: I *suspect* you need to pre-aggregate. It *looks* like your 2 subqueries aren't fully correlated, so you likely have a cartesian product.

Comment: As a side note, it appears that your are storing your dates () as 8-digit integers (year*10000 + Month*100 + day). If at all possible, I suggest that you convert your database design to use proper date types.  This would greatly simplify your date calculations and comparisons, and is just good design practice.

Answer (score 1):

The two `outer apply`s in your query effectively form *multiple independent one-to-many joins*, which can cause data duplication and inflated aggregated results. For example, if you had 3 matching tTypeID = 1234 rows and 4 matching tTypeID = 2345 rows, the combined joins would yield 12 result rows feeding the group-by. The 1234 rows would be counted 4 times each and the 2345 rows would be counted 3 times each.

The solution is to move the aggregation inside the outer-apply, so that each yields exactly one row of already-aggregated data. (The outer-apply could actually become a cross-apply at that point.)

Try:

```
SELECT 
        f.dID,
        f.edID,
        f.tTypeID,
        f.Amount,
        f.MKey,
        E.[111 Trans],
        E.[111 Amount],
        D.[222 trans],
        D.[222 Amount]
FROM wh.fct.Account FAT 
    JOIN wh.fct.ttype tt 
        ON tt.tTypeID = f.tTypeID
           AND tt.bID = 3
           AND f.dID >= 20221101
           AND tt.TrnCode = 2310
           AND f.MKey = 1234
    CROSS APPLY (
        select
            count(f1.MKey) AS [222 trans],
            sum(f1.Amount) AS [222 Amount]
        from wh.fct.Account f1 -- // 222
        where f1.MKey = 1234567
           AND f1.tTypeID = 1234
           AND f1.bID = 3
        and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f1.edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
        --      group by f1.InstId,
        --          f1.MKey,
        --          f1.Amount
        )
    ) D
    Outer APPLY (
        -- // 111
        select
            count(f2MKey) AS [111 trans],
            sum(f1.Amount) AS [111 Amount]
        from wh.fct.Account FAT2
        where f2MKey = 1234567
           AND f2tTypeID = 2345
           AND f2bID = 3
            and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f2edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
        -- group by 
        --        f2InstId,
        --       f2MKey,
        --       f2amount
    ) E

group by
        f.MKey,
        f.dID,
        f.edID,
        f.tTypeID,
        f.Amount
```

I am unsure what the intended purpose of the inner `GROUP BY`s. I have tentatively commented them out. It is unusual to see a `GROUP BY ...Amount`, where that amount is eventually fed into a `SUM(Amount)`. That can lead to accidental dropping of amounts from the calculation just because they match other amounts.

If the inner group-bys are needed, you can wrap them into a subselect within the cross-apply:

```
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            count(D.MKey) AS [222 Trans],
            sum(D.amount) AS [222 Amount]
        FROM (
            select f1.InstId,f1.MKey,f1.Amount
            from wh.fct.Account f1 
            where f1.MKey = 1234567
               AND f1.tTypeID = 1234
               AND f1.bID = 3
               and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f1.edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
            group by f1.InstId,
                  f1.MKey,
                  f1.Amount
        ) D
    ) D
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            count(E.MKey) AS [111 Trans],
            sum(E.amount) AS [111 Amount]
        FROM (
            Select InstId, MKey, f2.amount
            from wh.fct.Account FAT2
            where f2MKey = 1234567
               AND f2tTypeID = 2345
               AND f2bID = 3
               and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f2edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
            group by 
                f2InstId,
                f2MKey,
                f2amount
        ) E
    ) E
```

I believe you can also combine the two cross-applys by selecting both tTypeID values in the subquery and using *conditional aggregation* to later separate the values.

```
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            count(CASE WHEN tTypeID = 2345 THEN D.MKey END) AS [111 Trans],
            sum(CASE WHEN tTypeID = 2345 THEN D.amount END) AS [111 Amount],
            count(CASE WHEN tTypeID = 1234 THEN D.MKey END) AS [222 Trans],
            sum(CASE WHEN tTypeID = 1234 THEN D.amount END) AS [222 Amount]
        FROM (
            select f1.tTypeID, f1.InstId, f1.MKey, f1.Amount
            from wh.fct.Account f1 -- 111/222
            where f1.MKey = 1234567
               AND f1.tTypeID IN (2345, 1234)
               AND f1.bID = 3
               and CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f1.edID)) between CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID))  and dateadd(DAY,10,CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8),f.edID)))
            group by
                  f1.tTypeID,
                  f1.InstId,
                  f1.MKey,
                  f1.Amount
        ) D
    ) D
```